# apt-get autoremove wants to remove linux headers

Tags: apt

Today I ran `apt-get autoremove` to remove un-needed packages and it wants to remove `linux-headers-3.2.0-37` and `linux-headers-3.2.0-37-generic`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
libglademm-2.4-1c2a linux-headers-3.2.0-37 linux-headers-3.2.0-37-generic ttf-umefont    ttf-unfonts-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 67.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Is it safe to remove these?
My installed kernel is a newer version than the headers that autoremove lists.

```
uname -r
3.2.0-38-generic
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it is safe to remove the old kernel and headers as you are using a higher kernel.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure why autoremove wanted to remove the old kernel though. They usually stick.

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly safe as it isn't the same version. However you can check if you have headers installed for your version *3.2.0-38-generic* with this command:`apt-cache policy linux-headers-3.2.0-38-generic`.