# Autoremove wants to remove 127 (~5 Gb) packages

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

I know there are [several](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720239/apt-get-autoremove-dangerous) [other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259981/apt-get-autoremove-wants-to-remove-linux-headers) [similar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948435/apt-autoremove-wants-to-delete-over-1gb-of-files) questions but I think my case is extreme. `autoremove` wants to get rid of all the packages/libraries listed below. That's more than 5 Gb of stuff!

Is there anything in there that looks like it will break my system if removed?

```
  dkms gconf2 krita-data libcuda1-340 libevent-2.1-6 libexpat1-dev libgsl23 libgslcblas0 libllvm8 libminizip1 libmpv1
  libopencolorio1v5 libpython3-dev libpython3.6-dev libqgsttools-p1 libqt5concurrent5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins
  libqt5multimediaquick-p5 libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5webengine-data libqt5webengine5 libqt5webenginecore5
  libre2-4 libyaml-cpp0.5v5 linux-headers-4.15.0-54 linux-headers-4.15.0-54-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-55
  linux-headers-4.15.0-55-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-58 linux-headers-4.15.0-58-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-60
  linux-headers-4.15.0-60-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-62 linux-headers-4.15.0-62-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-64
  linux-headers-4.15.0-64-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-65 linux-headers-4.15.0-65-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-66
  linux-headers-4.15.0-66-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-70 linux-headers-4.15.0-70-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-72
  linux-headers-4.15.0-72-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-74 linux-headers-4.15.0-74-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-88
  linux-headers-4.15.0-88-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-91 linux-headers-4.15.0-91-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-96
  linux-headers-4.15.0-96-generic linux-image-4.15.0-54-generic linux-image-4.15.0-55-generic linux-image-4.15.0-58-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-60-generic linux-image-4.15.0-62-generic linux-image-4.15.0-64-generic linux-image-4.15.0-65-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-66-generic linux-image-4.15.0-70-generic linux-image-4.15.0-72-generic linux-image-4.15.0-74-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-88-generic linux-image-4.15.0-91-generic linux-image-4.15.0-96-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-54-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-55-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-58-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-60-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-62-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-64-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-65-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-66-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-70-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-72-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-74-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-88-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-91-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-96-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-54-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-55-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-58-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-60-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-62-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-64-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-65-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-66-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-70-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-72-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-74-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-88-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-91-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-96-generic
  python-asn1crypto python-attr python-automat python-cffi-backend python-click python-colorama python-constantly
  python-cryptography python-enum34 python-hyperlink python-idna python-incremental python-ipaddress python-lzma
  python-openssl python-pam python-parsley python-pyasn1 python-pyasn1-modules python-serial python-service-identity
  python-six python-twisted python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core python-txsocksx python-zope.interface
  qml-module-qt-labs-platform qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtwebchannel qml-module-qtwebengine torsocks
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you on? Looks like 18.04 but I'd need to be certain.

Comment: Yes, it's 18.04

Comment: This does not look extreme, and looks quite like the dupes you cited.

Comment: Of this list, only `libevent-2.1-6`, `libexpat1-dev`, `python-asn1crypto`, `python-cffi-backend`, `python-cryptography`, `python-enum34`, `python-idna`, `python-ipaddress`, `python-six` are installed on my 18.04 system. So I'd guess that your system won't be *entirely* broken after autoremove. Moreover, the sheer volume of the packages to be removed is easily explained by the older kernels, headers and modules that you've kept around. I'd say take the plunge.

Comment: Note: I always take a complete system backup using a LIVE cd (I use Redo) before I do anything like this.  It saved me yesterday when I had to restore both hard drives from backup after trying to remove ecryptfs.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you go with `sudo apt autoremove` , and **[NOT** `remove *`**]** you're good to go. You must haven't done that for quite a long time.